# Error ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7 en java

Tags: java, oracle

Este es mi procedimiento en oracle:

```
function DireccionCompleta_Empleados(p_codcia varchar2, p_codsuc varchar2, p_codtra char) 
  return types.cursortype is

  ap_cursor types.cursorType;
  BEGIN

    open ap_cursor for
    select 
    empcodtra,
    (select dptdes  from hr_depto where dptcod=empcoddept ) as Depto,
    (select prvdes  from hr_provin where prvcod=empcodprov ) as Prov,
    (select disdes  from hr_distri where discod=empcoddist ) as Distri,
    (select ttbdesobj  from eb_ttable where ttbcodcia=p_codcia and ttbcodsuc=p_codsuc and ttbcodtab='03' and ttbkeyobj=EMPCODVIA) as TipoVia,
    EMPDIRECCION as NombreVia, 
    EMPNUMDOM as NumDomicilio, 
    EMPDIRDEPA as Dpto, 
    EMPINTER as Interior, 
    EMPDIRMZN as Manzana, 
    EMPDIRLOTE as Lote,
    EMPDIRKM as Km,
    EMPDIRBLOCK as Bloque,
    EMPDIRETAPA as Etapa,
    (select ttbdesobj  from eb_ttable where ttbcodcia=p_codcia and ttbcodsuc=p_codsuc and ttbcodtab='04' and ttbkeyobj=EMPCODZONA) as TipoZona,
    EMPDESZONA as NombreZona,
    EMPREFEREN as Referencia
    from hr_empleado
    where empcodcia=p_codcia and empcodsuc=p_codsuc and empcodtra=p_codtra;
    RETURN ap_cursor;

  END;
```

En java tengo esto:

```
public ArrayList<BeanHR_EMPAPROBACION> ObtDireccionEmpleado(String p_codcia, String p_codsuc, String p_codtra)
            throws Exception {
        ArrayList<BeanHR_EMPAPROBACION> lista = new ArrayList<BeanHR_EMPAPROBACION>();
        BeanHR_EMPAPROBACION empa = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DBcon.getConnection();
        try {
            CallableStatement cstmt = (CallableStatement) conn
                    .prepareCall("{?= call EBBD.PKG_RH_APROBACIONES.DireccionCompleta_Empleados(?,?,?)}");
            cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            cstmt.setString(2, p_codcia);
            cstmt.setString(3, p_codsuc);
            cstmt.setString(4, p_codtra);

            cstmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) cstmt.getObject(1);

            while (rs.next()) {
                empa = new BeanHR_EMPAPROBACION();
                empa.setDepto(rs.getString("Depto"));
                empa.setProv(rs.getString("Prov"));
                empa.setDistri(rs.getString("Distri"));
                empa.setTipoVia(rs.getString("TipoVia"));
                empa.setNombreVia(rs.getString("NombreVia"));
                empa.setNumDomicilio(rs.getString("NumDomicilio"));
                empa.setDpto(rs.getString("Dpto"));
                empa.setInterior(rs.getString("Interior"));
                empa.setManzana(rs.getString("Manzana"));
                empa.setLote(rs.getString("Lote"));
                empa.setKm(rs.getString("Km"));
                empa.setBloque(rs.getString("Bloque"));
                empa.setEtapa(rs.getString("Etapa"));
                empa.setTipoZona(rs.getString("TipoZona"));
                empa.setNombreZona(rs.getString("NombreZona"));
                empa.setReferencia(rs.getString("Referencia"));
                lista.add(empa);
                rs.close();
                cstmt.close();
                System.out.println("Error de conexion para HUMAN :"+cstmt);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Mensaje de error Sql: "+e.getMessage());

        }finally{
            conn.close();
        }


        return lista;

    }
```

En la consola de java me sale este error:

> ```
> Mensaje de error Sql: ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 38:
> PLS-00302: component 'DIRECCIONCOMPLETA_EMPLEADOS' must be declared
> ORA-06550: línea 1, columna 7:
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored
> ```

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que veo es una funcion dentro de un paquete, debes declarar la funcion en el spec del mismo de esta forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE "PKG_RH_APROBACIONES" AS

function DireccionCompleta_Empleados(p_codcia varchar2, p_codsuc varchar2, p_codtra char);

end;
```

Otra cosa, no estoy seguro, pero creo que las funciones no pueden devolver set de datos (cursor), deberias usar un procedimiento y enviarlo por el parametro de salida.